# ASP.NET Performance Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, performance, asp.net-ajax

I am working on an ASP.NET 3.5, C#, ASP.NET AJAX, JQUERY web application which currently is having some performance issues. I have a screen with the forms view control and when I edit the form and save it for the first time the POST takes 4.89 seconds and when I perform the same operation again for the second time the POST only takes 1.09 seconds. What could be the reason for this strange behavior?

Note: I am using firebug and I am disregarding the page resources (like js, images) load time.

**EDIT:** I am using the Web Deployment Project to precompile the application.

Comment: Is this a fresh build in debug mode, or does it occur the first time in any session, even if the web server has not been restarted?

Comment: Does it have to do with the database creating / caching query plans or query results?

Answer (score 2):

Are you on your local machine or on a production machine?

If this is the first time you build, remember .NET apps are usually quite slow when loading the first page.  After that it usually picks up.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you have <compilation debug="false" /> within the <system.web> element of your Web.config files. It's a common issue that Scott Hanselman even mentioned on a recent post of the most common ASP.NET issues faced by MS support folks:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MostCommonASPNETSupportIssuesReportingFromDeepInsideMicrosoftDeveloperSupport.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you precompile your ASP.NET application it will improve the performance of the first request.  You can do this with the Publish tool in Visual Studio.

Comment: That's only for Website projects right?  Not sure if he specified what he's using.

Comment: Yeah I believe its only for a website project.  I could not find the same option available with a Web Application project.  Too bad.  But there is also a new option available in asp.net 4.0 that sort of pre-warms the application for you.  More details on Scott Gu's blog, http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: You can also NGEN the precompiled assembly on the target server to get even better performance of the first request.